# If all partial derivatives 0f $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ equal $0$ at $(x,y)$ then $f$ is not injective in neighborhood of $(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If you have a map $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and know that a point $(x,y)$ is a maximum, then $D_1f(x,y)=0$ and $D_2f(x,y)=0$.  It's clear that the converse doesn't always hold, but is it true that in some neighbhourood of $(x,y)$ that $D_1f(x,y)=0$ and $D_2f(x,y)=0$ imply that $f$ is not injective n a neighborhood of $(x,y)$?

Comment: I know you are right if $f$ is $C^1$ but not sure about simply differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually *no* continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ that is injective in any neighborhood of any point.  Intuitively, the idea is that you can't squeeze a plane injectively into a line, since a line has only one dimension.  More rigorously, you can prove this by restricting $f$ to a small circle in your neighborhood and considering the path $f$ takes along that circle.  For $f$ to be injective and continuous, it would need to be strictly monotone as you go around the circle.  But that is impossible, since it must come back to where it started after looping all the way around the circle.

If you don't assume that $f$ is continuous everywhere and merely assume that $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist and are $0$ at your single point $(x,y)$, then there are counterexamples.  As a sketch, you can take $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ and let $f$ map annuli around the origin bijectively to intervals approaching $0$, with the intervals getting to $0$ fast enough that $D_1f(0,0)$ and $D_2f(0,0)$ are $0$.

Comment: When you say "the path that $f$ takes along that circle", I recall the way to do this is to fix one of the variables and substitute a function such as $sinx$--in some form-- to take the path along the circle.  Could you write the representation of the subset of the domain that takes the path along the circle? 
 Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to consider $f$ along a circle centered at a point $(a,b)$ of radius $r$, you can consider the function $g(t)=f(a+r\cos t,b+r\sin t)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Awesome!  And I didn't exactly get your point about not being able to "squeeze a plane injectively into a line".  Although it seems obvious that there must be points on a line that are not uniquely mapped to I'm unsure of what actually guarantees this.  Is there a cardinality proof or a slick proof that finds $2$ points in $\mathbb{R^2}$ that map to the same element in $\mathbb{R}$?  Thanks again!

Comment: What guarantees it is exactly the argument using a circle which I sketched.  Cardinality does not help; there are injections from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but no _continuous_ injections.